# SQL Server 2005 - Nested recursive query :(

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, correlated-subquery

I have a query that I need to execute that I do not know how to structure.

I have a table called Employees. I have another table called Company. There is a third table called Files. As you can imagine, a Company has Employees, and Employees have Files.

I need to list out all of the Employees in my database. The challenge is, I need to list the total number of Files in the same company as the Employee. I have tried variations on the following without any luck:

```
SELECT
  e.FirstName,
  e.LastName,
  e.Company,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Files f WHERE f.EmployeeID IN (SELECT [ID] FROM Employees e2 WHERE e2.CompanyID=e.CompanyID)) as 'FileCount'
FROM
  Employees e
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to get.  Definately a list of all employees, but what should "FileCount" be?  The number of files that **Employee** has?  Or the number of files that Employee's **Company** has?

Comment: @Dems: he spells it out pretty clearly: "I need to list the total number of Files in the same company as the Employee"

Comment: @Kip: With all due respect, that's not how others have interpretted the OP.  I interpretted it as you did, others interpretted differently.  This I asked for clarification.  If you have issues with people asking for clarification, I suggest you ask yourself why it's an issue to you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  e.FirstName,
  e.LastName,
  e.Company,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Files f
    JOIN Employees e2 ON f.EmployeeID = e2.id
    WHERE e2.CompanyID = e.CompanyID
  ) as 'FileCount'
FROM
  Employees e
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to get that. If the performance is a concern, this is more optimal according to estimated execution plan costs.

```
SELECT
  e.FirstName,
  e.LastName,
  e.Company,
  COUNT(f.FileId)
FROM
  Employees e
  INNER JOIN Files f ON e.EmployeeID = f.EmployeeID
GROUP BY
  e.FirstName,
  e.LastName,
  e.Company
```

Comment: but won't this just give the number of files that the given employee has?  he wants the number of files for all employees in the same company as a given employee

Comment: Every employee belongs to a company, every file joined belongs to one employee. The query returns the employee information plus their number of files. You could filter it at the end to be WHERE e.Company = xxx.

Comment: I'm with Kip - this just gives each employee and their file count. So Bob has 2 files and Jim has 5 for Company "A". The OP said they wanted file counts for the entire company the employee is in. So Bob and Jim should both read 5 as there are are 5 totals files for company "A".

Comment: Whoops - typo. I meant Bob has 2 and Jim has 3. So 5 total. :)

Comment: @WesleyJohnson, yes if the requirement is that (FileCount is the total files for the company of the employee, instead of the total files for the employee) then the @Kip approach is the one :)
Let's see what the author of the question has to say.

Comment: @David Elizondo: he seems to put it pretty clearly: "I need to list the total number of Files in the same company as the Employee"

Answer (score 1):

A solution with no correlation in SELECT clause. Probably quicker...

```
SELECT
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.Company,
    foo.FileCount
FROM
    Employees e
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT
       COUNT(*) AS FileCount, --OR COUNT(DISTINCT something) ?
       e2.Company, f.EmployeeID
    FROM
       Files f JOIN Employees e2 ON f.EmployeeID = e2.id
    GROUP BY
       e2.Company, f.EmployeeID
    ) foo ON e.Company = foo.Company AND e.id = foo.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT
   e.FirstName,
   e.LastName,
   e.Company,
   select count(*) from Files f, Employees e where f.EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID and e.CompanyID=emp.CompanyID
FROM
  Employees emp
```

Comment: bad idea to use pre ANSi-92 join (in the WHERE clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH FilesPerCompany (CompanyID, NumberOfFiles)
AS (SELECT      c.ID AS CompanyID,
                COUNT(*) AS NumberOfFiles
    FROM        Companies c
    INNER JOIN  Employees e ON  c.ID = e.CompanyID
    INNER JOIN  Files f     ON  e.ID = f.EmployeeID
    GROUP BY    c.ID
)

SELECT      e.FirstName,
            e.LastName,
            e.Company,
            COALESCE(s.NumberOfFiles, 0) AS NumberOfFilesPerCompany
FROM        Employees e
LEFT JOIN   FilesPerCompany s
        ON  s.CompanyID = e.CompanyID
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement uses recursive joins to iterate down employees who manage other employees who manage other employees .... etc. Our structure is a little convoluted as the management structure is role based which actually allows an employee to have more than 1 manager. You can add a reference to Files within this recursion.

```
WITH Manager as
(SELECT c.Forenames + ' ' + c.Surname as Employee,
  c2.Forenames + ' ' + c2.Surname AS Manages,
  c.accountid AS AccountID, c.[Status] AS [Status]
  FROM [intranet].[dbo].[tblContact] c
  LEFT JOIN tblContactPost cp ON cp.contactid = c.contactid
  LEFT JOIN tblPost p ON p.ParentRoleId = cp.RoleID AND p.ParentPostArea = cp.PostArea AND p.ParentPostNo = cp.PostNo
  INNER JOIN tblContactPost cp2 ON cp2.RoleId = p.RoleId AND cp2.PostArea = p.PostArea AND cp2.PostNo = p.PostNo
  INNER JOIN tblContact c2 ON c2.ContactID = cp2.ContactId
  )
  ,jn AS
  (SELECT Employee, Manages
    FROM Manager
    Where AccountID = 'ad\lgardner' AND [Status] = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Employee, c.Manages
    FROM jn as p JOIN Manager AS c
    ON c.Employee = p.Manages
    )
SELECT jn.Employee, jn.Manages
From jn
Order BY 1
```